# WooCommerce manually create an orden doesn't let me add a customer nor shipping information

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce>Orders>Add orders doesn't show the Customers dropdown and other details you should be able to add aside from products/items and fees.

[Woocommerce Add Order screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBm7f.png)

Please how can I solve this? Is it a setting or a permission I have to enable?

I tried creating the order first, and after created tried to add a customer but it just lets you manage the items and change the status

[Created orders screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR60j.png)